# Does this sentence contain a redundant "la"?

Tags: traducción, gramática

It seems to me that this sentence:

> "[...] asalto con violencia y de usar un lenguaje soez e inmoral en presencia de **la la** señora."

...from the translation of "To Kill a Mockingbird" ("Matar a un ruiseñor") contains a redundant "la".

If not, what is the reason for the doubled "la"?

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake; it should be with a single "la".

Comment: Voted to reopen. Is quite clear to me what is being asked: if the sentence contains a mistake or typo due to a redundant "la" (I improved the formatting to  make it more clear) or if not what is the reason to have the "la la señora". I see no reason why that is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a mistake with the second "la". There is another error. The last word is "senoras" in plural and without the "ñ". Should be "señora".